# Regex Javascript - Invalid regular expression: Nothing to repeat for number input

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex pattern `/^-?+(\d+)?+([\.\,]?\d?+)/`. It has to allow `-` sign for negative values at the start, also allows zero value and any numbers with one dot or comma only. I tested it on https://regex101.com/ and it works fine there however when I wanted to use in my React project i get this error and dont exactly know what cause this problem.

> Module parse failed: Invalid regular expression: /^-?+(\d+)?+([.\,]?\d?+)/: Nothing to repeat (22:26)

Comment: You need to escape `+` it is a meta-character in regex

Comment: "*I tested it on https://regex101.com/ and it works fine*" it [throws a pattern error](https://regex101.com/r/gg08QO/1/) if you switch to ECMAScript (JavaScript) on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `+` is metacharacter in regex which acts as a quantifier, you need to escape it if you want to match `+` literally
- `[\]` - Inside character class before `, and .` is not needed

You can update your regex to this

```
^[-+]?(\d+)(?:[.,]?\d+)?$
```

[image]

```js
let nums = ["-1234", "+1232,1232", "+1234.12342,123"]

nums.forEach(num => {
  console.log(/^[-+]?(\d+)(?:[.,]?\d+)?$/.test(num))
})
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/1qCRi5/1/)